# Can't get value of designMode IFRAME

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, designmode

I can't retrieve the contents of an iframe, when `designmode = 'on'`. Here is my code:

```
val = $("#frame").val();
```

I've tried everything, and nothing works, help?

Comment: not an answer: may I know what is `designmode = 'on'` ?

Comment: @Reigel: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/rich-text_editing_in_mozilla   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533720%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var iframe = $("#frame")[0];
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var val = iframeDoc.body.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `.contents().find('body').html()`.

Comment: Try `.contents().children().html()`.